# C - Fclose -> Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am getting an error of Aborted on fclose want to know where I am doing wrong. Core Duped:

```
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0022A698  7C802542  (00000758, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 0022A794)
0022A7B8  610DC559  (000007DD, 0000000A, 00000032, 0000000B)
0022A8A8  610D9913  (00000000, 7C801879, 0022FF44, 7C839AC0)
0022A908  610D9DEE  (00000144, 00000000, 0022AC30, 00000006)
0022A9B8  610D9F40  (00000288, 00000006, 00000001, 200586E0)
0022A9D8  610D9F6C  (00000006, 00000006, 0022AA38, 610FCCE7)
0022AA08  610DA233  (7C809C1B, 00000744, 0022AA68, 610FCE07)
20038678  61110408  (61201C98, 00000000, 20010410, 00000001)
End of stack trace
```

I am using Cygwin + GCC + Autotools for the project. Didn't understand what that means. After this point nothing is there as the program has to exit but showing Aborted is disturbing..

Comment: Ahh, good old 7C802542. (No, seriously, we need to see some code :)

Comment: check your code if are you calling fclose() , more than once on a same pointer

Comment: I am sure calling only once 100% sure

Answer (score 4):

One standard way to get a core dump from `fclose()` is to pass it a file pointer that's null, because you failed to open the file:

```
 FILE *fp = fopen("/long/hairy/path/with/a/missing/file/at/the/end", "r");

 fclose(fp);
```

Always check the return value from `fopen()` and its relatives:

```
if (fp == NULL)
    ...report problem
else
{
    ...use fp...
    fclose(fp);
}
```